# How does moving a site to a host in an other country affect my google ranking?

Tags: ranking, google-ranking

If I move my website, which is hosted in Europe, to a host based in Asia, could it hurt my ranking in Google search?

I will keep my domain registrar in Europe, so my guess is that the ranking will not be affected.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt Cutts covers this in two videos:

[What impact does server location have on rankings?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXt23AXlJJU)
[Can the geographic location of a web server affect SEO?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keIzr3eWK8I)

Basically, it does affect your rankings, but primarily for personalized search results.

Answer (score 0):

It could affect your ratting indirect. If your site is for the european market, google will try to crawl it with eruopean google crawlers and if the hosting will be in Asia the page load speed will increase. This could affect negative your position in SERP